# How to create HTML form in which after user inputs email and clicks submit an email is sent to them from my gmail account?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, gmail

I have an HTML form such as

```
<form name="contact-form" method="POST" action="sendemail.php">
        <label>Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" required="required">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="required">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" required="required">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now I want this such that when a user of my website enters their name and their email address and clicks submit a pdf is emailed to them on that email address from my Gmail. How would I go about writing sendemail.php for it?

Tried max's answer:

```
<?

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'sample1@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'mypassword';                               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for


//From email address and name
$mail->From = "sample1@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Josh Bealer";

//To address
$mail->addAddress("receiveremail@gmail.com");

//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Blah</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

$mail->send();
?>
```

Comment: are you shure you setup you gmail account in a way that you can access it from a "unknown" location?

Comment: @MaxMuster My code is https://pastebin.com/fLetQqKg and it is saved as sendemail.php, when I visit localhost/sendemail.php it just shows the php code but does not "execute" it?

Comment: have you installed php ? what version is it ?

Comment: On ubuntu php --version
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 (cli) (built: May 26 2020 13:09:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies @MaxMuster

Comment: I just realized that I should use <?php instead of <? since I don't have that configured. I used that and now when go to localhost/sendemailjosh.php I get a blank screen but nothing in inbox. To be more specific my sendemailjosh.php is in var/www/html @MaxMuster

Answer (score 1):

You can be cool and write a method using this https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php

of you use the classic PHPmailer : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

on a debianoid you could try this:

```
apt install libphp-phpmailer
```

it will install you the PHPmailer class from ( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer )

then you can follow the example from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

I think it makes no sense that I copy the code from there for you ...

I made a super simple version

```
//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                    // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';               // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                           // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'josh@gmail.com';               // your SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'your_gmail_password';          // your SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS; // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
$mail->Port       = 587;                            // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for


//From email address and name
$mail->From = "josh@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Josh Bealer";

//To address
$mail->addAddress("recepient@example.com");

//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

try {
    $mail->send();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I think I will use PHPmailer. Thanks @Max Muster. Any tutorial or anything that explains how to like code what I want to do where when a user of my website enters their name and their email address and clicks submit a pdf is emailed to them on that email address from my Gmail?

Comment: yes, there is a simple example there :  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

Comment: thanks. How does it check though that my gmail is valid and I am the owner of the gmail?

Comment: take a look on the example I submitted. it asks you gmail user and password

Comment: Thanks. Will get back to you if stuck

Comment: you can install it with `sudo apt install libphp-phpmailer` or `apt install libphp-phpmailer` if you are on debianoid

Comment: Here how are you checking if gmail is valid and you are the owner of the gmail? In your code I mean which you edited just now @Max Muster

Comment: Thanks for editing. Here from@yourdomain.com would be say josh@gmail.com ? @Max Muster

Comment: I did what you told me to. Why doesn't it send the email? @Max Muster

Comment: I edited you code ... added try catch .. tell me what the script say ..

Comment: if it gives no error you must check your gmail settings that gmail let you access your imap account from anywhere .. you will receive a email that somebody tried to access your account and stuff